# Algorithm Analysis (Big O and Big Omega)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I got this question wrong on an exam : Name a function that is neither O(n) nor Omega(n).

After attempting to learn this stuff on my own through youtube, I'm thinking this may be a correct answer:

> (n<sup>3</sup> (1 + sin n)) is neither O(n) nor Omega(n).

Would that be accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Name a function that is neither O(n) nor Omega(n)

Saying `f ∈ O(g)` means the quotient

```
f(x)/g(x)
```

is bounded from above for all sufficiently large `x`.

`f ∈  Ω(g)` on the other hand means the quotient

```
f(x)/g(x)
```

is bounded below away from zero for all sufficiently large `x`.

So to find a function that is neither `O(n)` nor `Ω(n)` means finding a function `f` such that the quotient

```
f(x)/x
```

becomes arbitrarily large, and arbitrarily close to zero on every interval `[y, ∞)`.

> I'm thinking this may be a correct answer: `(n^3 (1 + sin n))` is neither O(n) nor Omega(n).

Let's plug it in our quotient:

```
(n^3*(1 + sin n))/n = n^2*(1 + sin n)
```

The `n^2` grows to infinity, and the factor `1 + sin n` is larger than 1 for roughly three out of every six `n`. So one every interval `[y, ∞)` the quotient becomes arbitrarily large. Given an arbitrary `K > 0`, let `N_0 = y + K + 1` and `N_1` the smallest of `N_0 + i, i = 0, 1, ..., 4` such that `sin (N_0+i) > 0`. Then `f(N_1)/N_1 > (y + K + 1)² > K² + K > K`.

For the `Ω(n)` part, it's not so easy to prove, although I believe it is satisfied.

But, we can modify the function a bit, retaining the idea of multiplying a growing function with an oscillating one in such a way that the proof becomes simple.

Instead of `sin n`, let us choose `cos (π*n)`, and, to offset the zeros, add a fast decreasing function to it.

```
f'(n) = n^3*(1 + cos (π*n) + 1/n^4)
```

now,

```
         / n^3*(2 + 1/n^4), if n is even
f'(n) = <
         \  1/n           , if n is odd
```

and it is obvious that `f'` is neither bounded from above, nor from below by any positive constant multiple of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider something like a binary search. This is both O(log N) and Ω(log N). Since Omega is defined as a lower bound, it's not allowed to exceed the function itself -- so O(log N) definitely is not Ω(N).

I think some of the comments on the deleted answer deserve some...clarification -- perhaps even outright correction. To quote from CLRS, "Ω-notation gives a lower bound for a function to within a constant factor."

Since N<sup>2</sup> differs from N by more than a constant factor, N<sup>2</sup> is not Ω(N).

Comment: The constant factor means that a constant multiple of `g` is a lower bound for `f`, `N²` does belong to `Ω(N)`.